# Form action GET + Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sorry if I'm repeating a question, but I can't seem to solve this looking at other answers :(

I have a FORM with GET action:

```
<form action="tag" role="form" method="get">
```

Which contains a search input named "q"

What I want is that when I submit the form, the URL displayed in the navigation bar is:

```
http://localhost/web/tag/dress
```

Instead, of

```
http://localhost/web/tag?q=dress
```

In my .htaccess I have

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Which works fine when I access directly to:

```
http://localhost/web/tag/dress
```

All I want is the form to take me to this clean URL instead of using the ?q= parameter in the navigation bar.

Any suggestions?

**A simplified version of my .htaccess is:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/web/#404
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html index.php [L]

###TAG
RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?seccion=home&tag=$1[L]

###USER PROFILE
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?seccion=profile&user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you want to formulate a clean URL for your GET action from your form, you will need to use javascript to perform the GET submission. Likely this would involve preventing the default form behavior, building the destination URL based on the form's input values, and then changing the browser location to that URL.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if I am forced to do this with javascript?

Something like:

```
$('.search-form').submit(function (event) { 
    var tag = $('#q').val();
    window.location='tag/'+tag;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes exactly, though you probably want to write a function to do this, rather than have it all inline. This would allow the function to be reusable across multiple forms on your site and keep the logic cleanly separated from the HTML.

Comment: Yeap, Updated my answer with the code in JS. Tell me if you think it's a good solution :)

Comment: it looks suitable, however you would likely need to use `encodeURIComponent(tag)` to properly format value for use in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Add this additional rule before your existing rule:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+web/tag\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /web/tag/%1? [R=302,L]
```

**UPDATE:** Your complete .htaccess:
NOTE: "/" was missing. Now it should work.

```
ErrorDocument 404 web/#404

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /web/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tag/\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ tag/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L,NC]

###TAG
RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?seccion=home&tag=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

###USER PROFILE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?seccion=profile&user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Nothing. When I hit enter, my form still jumps to /tag?q=query instead of /tag/query/

Comment: Did you place this rule before your existing rule? Do you have some other rules in your .htaccess also?

Comment: Yes, I tried before with no results. Other rules I have are: RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html index.php [L]

###TAG
RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?seccion=home&tag=$1&module=trending [L]

Comment: That is strange since I have tested this rule and it works. Is this your complete URL: `http://localhost/web/tag?q=dress`?

Comment: Yeah, so I search for something and it comes up as: http://localhost/web/tag?q=dress but I want the *displayed* URL in the navigation bar to be http://localhost/web/tag/dress

Comment: Plese note that both of these URLs are funtional, they both point to the same place. But when submitting the form I would like the "clean version" instead of the organic ?q= Get method

Comment: I'm not sure that would work as localhost/web/ is already the base location. Let me post my .htaccess on my original post to see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Still no results... grr! Must be something wrong with my local server configuration I guess. I'm going to go with the javascript solution for now. Thanks for your contribution though, I know it has worked for others!

Comment: It is really baffling that this simple tested rule isn't working for you. DO you have any other .htaccess in the system by any chance OR any PHP/CMS framework in place?