# mod_rewrite GET form to clean URL

Tags: php, forms, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried searching but only came up with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054072/form-action-get-mod-rewrite) which I can get to work, just not correctly to apply to my current situation.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/highscores/personal/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user1=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /highscores/personal/%1? [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^highscores/personal/(.*)/vs/(.*) personal.php?user1=$1&user2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^highscores/personal/(.*) personal.php?user1=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^highscores/skill/(.*) highscores.php?skill=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^highscores/(.*) highscores.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

As of right now, it will redirect

```
http://localhost/highscores/personal/?user1=test
```

to

```
http://localhost/highscores/personal/test
```

like it should.

But I have a compare function which submits a GET request like:

```
http://localhost/highscores/personal/?user1=test&user2=test2
```

which needs to come out like

```
http://localhost/highscores/personal/test/vs/test2
```

but it comes out like

```
http://localhost/highscores/personal/test&user2=test2
```

Edit: Resolved using help from [this htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/highscores/personal/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user1=([^&]+)&user2=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /highscores/personal/%1/vs/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/highscores/personal/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user1=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /highscores/personal/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your rule

```
RewriteRule ^highscores/personal/(.*)/vs/(.*) personal.php?user1=$1&user2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^highscores/personal/([^/]+)/vs/(.*) personal.php?user1=$1&user2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

because of greedy regex. You need to break `(.*)` section if `/` is found